# Binding another Control's property to Custom control with Silverlight and Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-3.0

I've created a custom Control called EllipsisTextBlock with a DependencyProperty aiming to receive another Control's property value:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CopyTextBlockWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CopyTextBlockWidth", typeof(double), typeof(EllipsisTextBlock),
        new PropertyMetadata(0d, null));
```

In the EllipsisTextBlock's parent Grid, I'm binding the other Control's property like this:

```
<Grid Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MaxHeight="84"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MaxHeight="72"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" MaxHeight="120"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbxTeste" Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="28" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="0"></TextBlock>
        <extensions:EllipsisTextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="28" TextWrapping="Wrap" CopyTextBlockWidth="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=tbxTeste}" Grid.Row="0"></extensions:EllipsisTextBlock>
...
```

What happens is that EllipsisTextBlock's CopyTextBlockWidth property's Set is **never** called:

```
public double CopyTextBlockWidth
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(CopyTextBlockWidthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CopyTextBlockWidthProperty, value); }
    }
```

By the way, EllipsisTextBlock class have two other DependencyProperties which works.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is misleading using the XAML attribute syntax, SetBinding is called, not SetValue nor the CLR setter when you assign a binding to a property in XAML.

Comment: Sorry Ryan, I didn't get you.

Comment: I probably could have formatted that better.  When you make the assignment to your dependency property in XAML using a Binding.  WPF will call SetBinding on your control, so the setter is never called.

Comment: I got it now. So it means I need to change something or it will not work at all? I changed the behavior adding a callback method when defining the DependencyProperty, but it's not called also.

Comment: The binding will work.  EllipsisTextBlock will have a width of zero probably, because the TextBlock has Visibility set to Collapsed (which means take up no space).